High Insertion Loss on 4 Layer 5.8 GHz Board
I've built a board to serve as the front end of a 5.8 GHz Wi-Fi radio. The boards were built using OSH Park's 4-layer service, which uses ISOLA FR408-HR. It seems like these boards should be acceptable for use at 5.8 GHZ given their Df is relatively low (0.0092). However, whenever I test the full boards, I'm getting a high calculated insertion loss through the board.
I'm measuring the board through the following chain with a fieldfox network analyzer:
SMA Connector ⇾ Front End Antenna Switch ⇾ Tx/Rx Switch ⇾ LNA ⇾ U.fl output connector
Whenever I measure the system through this chain, I get an output S21 of 15.0 dB. The low noise amplifier has a gain of 26 dB so with the switch IC insertion losses, I have almost 10 dB extra of insertion loss between the SMA port and the RX test U.Fl port. I calibrated the network analyzer to eliminate cable losses. My question is: Is there anything wrong with the layout for the board? Should the microstrip traces as I've designed them work for 5.8 GHz? Or is it more likely that something is screwed up with one of ICs?
Couple of small notes: The S11 of the SMA connectors into the board is a bit high, it's only -6 dB. So the impedance discontinuity at the connector into the board is significant, but it doesn't account for the 10 dB of loss I'm seeing. Additionally, the SKY134460374LF TX/RX switch needed blocking capacitors and I didn't add them. I was able to cut the traces and expose a small pad to add another of the 0402 2.2 pf RF capacitors. The capacitors are from Murata's GQM family so they should work fine at high frequencies. Also, I only populated C35 and not C34 to couple the signal to the test path.
Here's what I would expect the S21 to be roughly based on the individual insertion losses/gains of each component (in the same order as the listing above):
(- 0.2 dB) ⇾ (- 1.4 dB) ⇾ (- 1.0 dB) ⇾ (+ 26.5 dB) ⇾ (- 0.6 dB) = 23.3 dB
Design Pictures and Schematics Below





Did you specify controlled impedance for the 15.3 mil traces when you manufactured the board, or did you just expect that the dimensions would be reproduced accurately enough? Can you section the boards to verify that the L1-L2 pre-preg layer actually came out to 8 mil after lamination?

Does the light green color around Q4 indicate a ground cut-out beneath this chip?

I didn't specify, details are here for Oshpark: https://docs.oshpark.com/services/four-layer/. They include a controlled impedance constraints that also says that 15 mils is what produces 50 ohm lines on their process. Was debating sectioning one of them as well to see if there's any major issues with the board stackup. And no that light green isn't a ground cutout, it's a courtyard for that footprint.

10 dB loss does seem high for just passive conductors.  Do you have other passive devices in the path, like a filter/diplexer, splitter, etc?

And have you done a chain analysis for the SMA Connector ⇾ Front End Antenna Switch ⇾ Tx/Rx Switch ⇾ LNA ⇾ U.fl output connector path you're trying to measure?  If so, please add it to your question.

@SteveSh I just added the full analysis. After being a bit more careful with the exact numbers, I have 8 dB extra loss in the board than what I expect when I use (conservative) values from the datasheets. There are no other passives that path that I'm testing except for DC block capacitors. The capacitors are GQM 2.2 pf 0402 from Murata though which should be fine.

Issues I see:

I don't see bypass capacitors near the power supply pin of U2.

You have traces on (I think) L2 pretty close to your high speed traces, breaking the reference plane for these traces. Having these traces break the ground connection between the area beneath the traces and the ground connection to U2 may be one of your biggest problems. If this is the issue you should see better performance for inputs on ANT4 and ANT5 than on ANT1, ANT2, ANT3.

The pads for your coax connectors are much wider than the trace width for 50 ohm microstrip. It would be good to place ground cut-outs below these pads to reduce their capacitance to ground (You haven't shown whether you did this or not).

The inductor you used for L6, the DC power feed to Q4, is resonant around 5 GHz (source Murata SimSurfing tool). Given your operating frequency at 5.8 GHz, this could be another significant problem.



(To reproduce the image:

Go to the SimSurfing page.
Select "Online Version".
Select "RF Inductors".
Enter part number in the "part number search" field e.g. LQG15HS6N8H02.
Click on the row for the part in the retrieved results.
Select "S-parameters" graph type.
Select series configuration if not already selected.
Select "S21" graph.
)

Minor things you could improve in your impedance calculation. These are not likely to account for 10 dB error in S21:

You assumed perfect vertical walls for the trace (W1 = W2). A 45 degree angle would be closer to reality (W2 = W1 - 2t).

The calculation of the trace thickness only allows for about 0.3 mils of plating (1.3 mils for the base 1 oz copper, plus ~.4 mils for any plating). This is probably an under-estimate, unless you've verified it with your manufacturer.

The Dk of FR408-HR prepreg at 5 GHz varies between about 3.3 and 3.6 depending on the specific weave used (and also on resin squeeze-out). (source) So your estimate of the Dk might be off by as much as 10%, depending which weave the manufacturer chooses to use.



Thanks for the detailed responses. Yep no capacitor on U2, don't know how much that would contribute, but I can probably add it. There aren't any traces on L2 except for ground, that's just an artifact of the transparent view. I didn't do a ground cutout on the SMA connectors, which is why I think S11 is high, doesn't approach 10 dB of loss though. Also for the S21 of the inductor, I used the same series recommended in eval board by minicircuits, just 6 nH instead of 10 nH. Is a high S21 not desirable for a choke inductor as that means little RF will pass through it?

@cEEa, Yes, high S21 is desirable for the choke, but it's hard to know how that resonance will interact with C44 and C45 and their parasitics and any board parasitics associated with them and their footprints, without  spending a couple hours on simulations.
